# How to merge git branches in RStudio

Tags: r, git, github, statistics, rstudio

I am a beginner to Git and GitHub. I came across tutorials on working with Git using RStudio. Instead of working from git bash RStudio offers a GUI type connection with Git and Github. Can someone tell me whether is it possible to merge git branches in RStudio? If so, how to do that?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 10):

I don't think that you can do that directly from the GUI of Rstudio.

You can (in Rstudio) go to GIT -> More -> Shell and perform the commands, but this is similar to just working from git bash.

(fatherly advice: learn git from the command line, it will benefit you in the long run, when you have to deal with more serious git-issues)